# How to remove a user from a MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb

I have a database to which I assigned one user that I want to remove right now.

My commands looks like:

```
> show dbs
admin     0.000GB
users     0.000GB
local     0.000GB
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "admin.myuser",
    "user" : "myuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I want to remove user `myuser` I'm using:

```
> db.dropUser(myuser)
2016-02-11T14:13:21.107+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: myuser is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

What is the reason for that and how can I remove this user from my database?

Comment: For anyone else looking to drop users, I found this to be helpful for dropping database specific users. https://tecadmin.net/create-drop-users-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 34):

The **[`db.dropUser()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.dropUser/)** method accepts a string parameter for username, in your case it's throwing an error because the argument is invalid.

Try using a string:

```
> use admin
> db.dropUser("myuser")
```

or run the **[`dropUser`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dropUser/)** command:

```
> use admin
> db.runCommand( { dropUser: "myuser" } )
```